# java Dangling meta character '+'

Tags: java, regex

I have text:

```
String str = "<HTML> <HEAD>\n" +
            "<TITLE>Управление разрывом строк </Title>\n" +
            "</HEAD>\n" +
            "<BODY>\n" +
            "<marquee>Это моя учебная страница.</marquee>\n" +
            "<H2>Меня зовут <kbd>Ольга. </kbd></H2>\n" +
            "<H3 align=\"center\">Я живу во <em>Владивостоке</em>.</H3>\n" +
            "<H4 align=\"right\">Моя маленькая родина - <font face=\"Academy\" color=\"Red\">Сахалин</font>. </H4>\n" +
            "<H5 align=left>ДВГУ - ВУЗ в котором я работаю.</H5>\n" +
            "<B>Здесь</B>\n" +
            "<I>продемонстрированы</I>\n" +
            "<Blink>различные</Blink>\n" +
            "<U> способы </U>\n" +
            "<KBD>управления </KBD>\n" +
            "<FONT SIZE=5 COLOR=FF80C0>шрифтом:</FONT> его\n" +
            "<FONT SIZE=5 COLOR=FF00FF>цветом</FONT> и\n" +
            "<FONT SIZE=+3 COLOR=FF00FF>размером.</FONT>\n" +
            "</BODY> </HTML>";
```

I write regexp `(?<=(=))[+a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=(>| ))` that find manches

1. left
2. 5
3. FF80C0
4. 5
5. FF00FF
6. +3
7. FF00FF

But java throw exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Dangling meta character '+' near index 0
+3
^
at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1955)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2123)
...
```

Ok. I try shield + (`(?<=(=))[\\+a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=(>| ))`)

But this no work(is the same error). Why?

code:

```
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("(?<=(=))[+a-zA-Z0-9]+(?=(>| ))").matcher(str);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        str= str.replaceAll(matcher.group(),'"' + matcher.group() + '"');
    }
```

Comment: because of this: FONT SIZE=+3
+ is a special char in regex

Comment: Where is the code that throws this exception? The error indicates you are using the `+3` as pattern.

Comment: my regex worked in https://regex101.com/r/x4Qudo/1 and others online regex

Comment: Unable to reproduce exception on [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/XmRO44)

Comment: @Henry I added code. sorry

Comment: Try using jsoup or another html parser instead of regex to extract html data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You error has nothing to do with the shown regex.

The problem is because you use the matched result values as a parameter to `replaceAll()`, and those parameters are *also* regular expressions.

Since you don't want them to be interpreted as regex, you need to escape them, or rather "quote" them, like this:

```
str = str.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(matcher.group()),
                     Matcher.quoteReplacement('"' + matcher.group() + '"'));
```

**UPDATE**

However, if you just want to put double-quotes around the matched strings, why don't you just use `replaceAll()` directly? Like this:

```
    str = str.replaceAll("(?<==)([+a-zA-Z0-9]+)(?=[> ])", "\"$1\"");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue does not come from your pattern, it comes from

```
replaceAll(...)
```

ReplaceAll takes a regex in input.

Your input comes from your str, and at some point it is "+3", which contain a dangling +...